# Karate archetype in settings.xml for maven

Tags: karate

I'm using maven latest version. I'm trying to configure Karatelabs in which i am trying to add karate archeype which is throwing error.
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.intuit.karate -DarchetypeArtifactId=karate-archetype  -DarchetypeVersion=0.9.6 -DgroupId=com.softwarethatmatters.karate.maven -DartifactId=karate-maven-setup

if anyone has settings.xml file for above configuration , that would help me a lot.

Comment: most likely your corporate network is blocking things. the documentation already suggests a workaround: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#quickstart - else try the ZIP release, I don't think anyone will be able to help you otherwise